# How did this appear in the first posts queue?

Tags: support, first-post-review

I just saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/12505794) in the First Posts queue, even though this user has [more than a hundred answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/688624/imallett?tab=answers).

How is this possible? Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the First Posts queue  as existing to review users' *first posts*?

Comment: It was an audit.

Comment: Oh. It was so unrealistic it didn't even occur to me that it was an audit. Thanks!